# Form help(HTML/JS)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm (very) new to web development and am working on learning back-end currently.

I am trying to figure out how to use multiple inputs inside a form, but am struggling to get the actual input, instead of the element itself using this code to create the form:

```
<form id="newPostForm">
  <input name="titleInput" placeholder="title"><br>
  <input name="bodyInput" placeholder="body">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

and this JS to try and output the user input to the console:

```
const newPost = document.getElementById("newPostForm")
const title = document.querySelector(".titleInput")
const body = document.querySelector(".bodyInput")

newPost.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(title, Body)
})
```

When I hit the submit button the console displays `null null`. This is probably a super simple question, but I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: `querySelector(".titleInput")` looks for an element with the *class* of `titleInput`, not the `name`. Also, you have `console.log(title, Body)` but your variable is `body` (lowercase)

Comment: document.getElementsByName("titleInput")[0].value

Comment: When starting a code block using triple-backticks, the first line of code needs to be on its own line.  If its on the same line as the opening backticks, it gets excluded.

Comment: Instead of putting your code edits in the comments, please edit the question. It's easier for everyone to follow that way

Comment: @j08691 The code in their comments was already in the question.  It was just a minor formatting problem with the backticks.

Comment: hm, I changed it to class but it's displaying the element, instead of the input. 
output:
            <input class="titleInput" placeholder="title">
            <input class="bodyInput" placeholder="body">

Comment: Rather than using a `<button>` element as the submit (which will technically work), I'd recommend using an `<input type="submit">` instead. There may be scenarios where you want a button in a form that doesn't result in a submission, in which case you'd want `<button type="button">`

Comment: Please, for the love, edit your edits into the question rather than posting them as comments (as someone already suggested you do). Take *a deep breath and 5 seconds*, and figure out how to actually use StackOverflow. It will save you *weeks if not years* over the course of your programming life as well as increasing your odds of getting meaningful help for any given question.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions and help, all.

@JaredSmith Someone already edited it when i went to do it myself, I just didn't delete the comments. My bad.

Comment: @BlackBriar there's not need to feel bad about it! Just do better next time :)

Answer (score 4):

After fixing the case issue with your `body` variable, you need to get the value of the inputs by accessing their `value` property. Then you want to move those variables into your submit handler, otherwise you're only getting the value once, when the page loads, and they're blank:

```js
const newPost = document.getElementById("newPostForm");
newPost.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  const title = document.querySelector(".titleInput").value;
  const body = document.querySelector(".bodyInput").value;
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log(title, body)
})
```

```html
<form id="newPostForm">
  <input name="titleInput" class="titleInput" placeholder="title"><br>
  <input name="bodyInput" class="bodyInput" placeholder="body">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```